# Using a broadband connection while on a network with an internet connection

Tags: networking, connection, adapter, internet-connection, broadband

So, in my workplace I use a laptop that I connect to a domain via ethernet, and the network there has an internet connection, however it's usually very slow and sometimes doesn't work at all, so I use a modem with a 3G cell to access the internet. **The problem** is that I have to disable the Ethernet adapter in order to use the ineternet connectivity from the modem.

Is there a way to use the modem without me having to disconnect myself from the domain?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are on windows going to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and then clicking advanced, advanced settings allows you to set the proiority of your networks, if you move your 3G network above ethernet it might solve your problem